# Get data from php Object that name have backslash

Tags: moodle

Hello I have Return data from sql that show me this :

```
tool_courserating\local\models\rating Object 
( [data:core\persistent:private] => Array 
( [id] => 3 [courseid] => 8 [userid] => 2 [rating] => 4 [review] => [hasreview] => 0 [timecreated] => 1702151698 [timemodified] => 1702151698 ) 
[errors:core\persistent:private] => Array ( ) 
[validated:core\persistent:private] => )
```

The code that come this result is :

```
$rating = (object) tool_courserating\local\models\rating::get_record(['courseid' => $courseData->id]);
print_r($rating);
```

I'm not php expert so Idk how to get rating from this object that I have! and if it's array how I can control it with foreach?(Ik it's Stupid Question)

------------------------Update---------------

The class That I Using it's from here :[Github SRC](https://github.com/marinaglancy/moodle-tool_courserating/blob/master/classes/local/models/rating.php)

Comment: The data seems to be private within the object so presumably you'd have to use some function of the object to access it. have a look at the code of that class, or any documentation you might have about it, to see what's available.

Comment: @ADyson updated with class

Comment: It seems to inherit from another class called `core\persistent` where those properties are actually defined. So the code of that class is likely to be more helpful to us.

Comment: Yes, ADyson is right. It is a [Persistent class](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Persistent) from Moodle. You should be able to get the rating with `$rating->get('rating');`. I can't be sure, because there's no way to test this.

Comment: I use hardcode and direct access to database for do that, but there is a way to handle problem like that? I use this     $rating = (array) $DB->get_record('tool_courserating_rating', ['courseid' => $courseId]);
    $result = $rating['rating'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool uses Moodle's persistent database class.

So you just need to use the `get` function for the rating

Also, there could be more than one rating for a course, so you should use `get_records` rather than `get_record`

```
 $ratings = \tool_courserating\local\models\rating::get_records(['courseid' => $courseData->id]]);

 foreach ($ratings as $rating) {
     echo $rating->get('rating');
 }
```